# How to connect a second battery to my UPS?

Tags: batteries, switch-mode-power-supply, ups

I have a UPS, its battery seem to be dying. Earlier it was giving a backup of 30 min, now it has come down to 10 min with the same load. I purchased a battery of the same capacity 12V 7amp, I was thinking of connecting this one with a 2-way switch, so I can use both batteries by switching it when one gets discharged. Is this a right thing to do, will it create a problem?

Answer (score 5):

You can't switch your battery under load, that would lead to an inevitable voltage drop on the generated voltage keeping your devices working, and thus negate the idea of a UPS.

So, give your old battery into recycling, and only use the new one – even using both in parallel (if that was possible, which is not *really* the case) would be giving you but 25% more capacity than just the new one, so simply write off the old battery.

Comment: How does adding a second battery in parallel only add 25% capacity?

Comment: And the UPS won't be designed to charge two batteries.

Comment: @JYelton, the 25% (or so) is from the original battery.

Comment: Putting aside UPS capabilities for now (I recognize they aren't designed to charge nor house extra batteries), adding an identical battery in parallel should maintain voltage while doubling capacity. Is the 25% figure due to the failing battery? I just am curious how 25% was arrived at.

Comment: @JYelton you already got an answer to that question from Transistor.

Comment: I asked as a [new question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/503108/2028) because I don't think comments were working for me.

Comment: i know that i can't switch it to other battery while on load but, is it safe to use a two way switch , so i can switch back and forth , or should i connect the new battery directly to the old battery in parallel  ? Which method would be best ?